# Handling passwords in custom MembershipProvider class in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm in the process of implementing a custom MembershipProvider class that utilizes my rich domain model. I'm hesitant because I want to ensure that I handle the passwords correctly. I'd like to hash the passwords in the database but I cannot seem to find any best practices or sample code that I trust to do this in ASP.NET. Is it possible to write a custom MembershipProvider class but somehow utilize the base class to handle the password details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid of hashing passwords on your own. Just few things to note.

1) Use a hash algorithm that is not compromised (MD5 is, sha256/sha512 are not as for now)

2) Always remember to store unique hash with your hashed password so that you have `hash = hashfunction( password + salt)`. This is to prevent someone from easily get your passwords using a precomputed hashes if the database is stolen.

3) (optional) Hash few, few hundred or few thousand times and store the round counter with your hashed password. This will further slow down anyone trying to get plaintext passwords from a stolen database.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will probably be to inherit from `SqlMembershipProvider` and then override most of the methods except for `EncryptPassword`, which would use the default ASP.NET behavior.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
}
```